# Match string from list of string

Tags: python

```
def email_delete(brwser):
    user_input = input("Would you like to delete some emails?: > Y/N")
    key_words = ["Order", "order", "Re:", "Purchase"]
    # email_indi_subject = []
    email_search(brwser)
    sleep(3)
    email_subjects = brwser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@data-testid='message- 
                                                                   column:subject']")
    
   if user_input == "y" or user_input == "Y":
       sleep(2)
       try:
           for subject in email_subjects:
               # sleep(0.25)
               # print(subject.get_property('title'))
               # email_indi_subject.append(str(subject.get_property('title')))

               if any(words in str(subject.get_property('title')) 
                                                              for words in key_words):
                print("Keep > " + subject.get_property('title'))
            else:
                print("Loss > " + subject.get_property('title'))

       except StaleElementReferenceException as sers:
            print(sers)

'''for keyw in key_words: # printing 4 times checking each individual keyword ??works i think??
    for subject in email_indi_subject:
        if keyw in subject:
            print("Keep: > " + subject)
        else:
            print("Loss: > " + subject) '''
```

I have been trying to match words from a list to individual subject(string) of each email though the problem is that I can't seem to match the words from a list to individual subjects. In doing so at the bottom I believe it works but has its downfalls obviously.

Comment: It looks like you are doing the test backwards. You probably want to iterate over the key words, iterating over a string iterates letter-by-letter. `any(word in title for word in key_words)`

Comment: `if user_input == "y" or "Y":`, this condition always is True. You should write `if user_input == "y" or user_input == "Y":`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only line you want to change is:

```
if any(words in str(subject.get_property('title')) for words in key_words):
```

Since you want at least one match, define this function:

```
def any_match(string, patterns):
    for pattern in patterns:
        if pattern in string:
            return True
    return False
```

and replace the line mentioned above by:

```
if any_match(str(subject.get_property('title')), key_words):
```

Answer (score 0):

ZoidEEE, You could use `.upper()` when you try to take input from the user. This method returns all lowercase letters in a string to `uppercase`. So you can use `y` instead of `"y"` or `"Y"` in the if statement.